# Notepad++ put padding on left side

Tags: notepad++

I need to shift the text to to the right side after 2-3 spaces.

[image]

I want to apply it to all the the lines..

Comment: Set your tab size to 3 spaces. Then select all the text (<ctrl><a>) or the text you want to indent and press <tab>.

Answer (score 0):

For moving all lines 3 tabs right you would just select all text and hit CTRL+TAB 3 times. 
To move it 3 spaces right, i recommend using regular expression replace like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey brother. thank you for sharing your answer. It worked.